# Dealing missing data as moving average of last 5 observations in time series in python

Tags: python, missing-data, moving-average

I have a time series data with date gaps as huge as 4 months. Whats the best way to fill those missing data values.

Data looks something like:

```
            Qty
Date
2016-04-01  0.125
2016-05-01  2.750
2016-06-01  4.825
2016-07-01  5.625
2016-08-01  2.475
2016-09-01  NaN
2016-10-01  NaN
2016-11-01  NaN
2016-12-01  1.000
2017-01-01  2.500
```

I have tried this:

```
data_mean = data.cumsum() / (~data.isna()).cumsum()
data_mean = data_mean.fillna(method = "ffill")
data = data.fillna(value = data_mean)
```

However, this dint worked out well for forecasting. I have also tried using interpolate() method as well, but dint get very good results.

Scenario is: places where there as missing values, no quantity was purchased on that date. I need to fill those missing dates in order to do forecasting later.

I want to try to fill the missing value with the moving average of last 5 observations to that corresponding missing value position, in python.
Please help in this context. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a for-loop to achieve this, something like this:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if pd.isna(df.iloc[i, 1]):
        moving = df.iloc[i-5:i, 1].mean()
        df.iloc[i, 1] = moving
```

Comment: Hi Djerro, thanks for the reply. Its throwing error. IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds.

Comment: Is any of you first 5 values a nan?

Comment: No, 6 and 7th values are nan

Comment: Fixed: for i in range(len(df)):
    if pd.isna(df['Qty'].iloc[i]):
        moving = data['Qty'].iloc[i-5:i].mean()
        data['Qty'].iloc[i] = moving